# Twitter is not showing thumbnail for my page

Tags: twitter, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to add a thumbnail when a user shares a page of my site. According to the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/guides/getting-started), it is necessary to define some parameters for the card i.e. image, title, description, etc. I am using the snippet on the page, however, when I share the card, my image does not show up.
This is my current `<head>`

```
<!-- Twitter open-graph tags -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@twitter_user">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@twitter_user">
<meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="Site name">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://examplesite.com/static/landing/img/img.png" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{% trans 'Site Title' %} - Site" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="{% trans 'Site description' %}" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://www.examplesite.com{% url path %}">
```

I am using the absolute path, i.e.: https://examplesite.com/img/img.png (adding my domain to load the image), also using the HTTPS protocol, with an image in PNG format of 80kb and 1200x630px.

When I want to validate my site with [this tool](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator), I get this result, in which the image is not visible and also, according to the log, not all the defined parameters are detected.

[image]

Comment: is your site publicly available without any geo fencing/specific firewall/web server rules setup that might be restricting the twitter bot from seeing your site?

Comment: The problem is visual and has already been explained in the question. I have posted the image as support.

Comment: Restarting your browser (close it and reopen it) and then running the Twitter tool again to rescrape your site sometimes shows the image. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66816822/1011984